# Use Cmder with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-10, cmder

I am new to bash and commandline, a friend adviced me to use Bash with Cmder so I downloaded it here : http://cmder.net/ (mini)

The problem is, that when I open it it emulates the standard command prompt and not Bash. I can't find where I can configure it.

When I say Bash I mean Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10.

Comment: What about MSYS2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows bash.exe is located in C:\Windows\System32, all you need to do from cmder shell is to use the full path:

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's how I did it:

in Settings, Tasks I added a "bash::ubuntu" task which I launch with :

`%windir%\system32\bash.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt`

(paste it in the big box in the lower right corner)

I even set up its icon with :

`-icon "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\lxss\bash.ico"`

(paste it in "Task parameter".)

And it works like a charm, I even set up a personnalised palette locked to bash::ubuntu (using Ap Distinct) that looks like the purple terminal from ubuntu.

BTW the latest version of ConEmu has already bash.exe setup under Bash::bash.

[image: Here's how it looks for me]

Comment: This no longer works or it doesn't work for me. I don't understand why it isn't working but it completely ignores this startup task and refuses to use Ubuntu, refuses to go to the home ~ folder and refuses to use the icon. I don't get why.

Comment: The same settings still work for me, cf. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch1UA.png
But I use directly Ubuntu for Windos or Mintty now so I've not kept up with it.
My Cmder version is 161206

Answer (score 4):

[Support for the new Windows 10 bash shell](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/901) is a closed issue now.
[Setting](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/901#issuecomment-237562623) could be done this way:

> You make a new task called Bash::Ubuntu
>
> Task parameters:
>
> /icon "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\lxss\bash.ico"
>
> Commands:
>
> cmd /k "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\bash.exe" -new_console:d:%USERPROFILE%
>
> Then you make a new task called Bash::Ubuntu as Admin
>
> Task parameters same as before Commands:
>
> *cmd /k "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\bash.exe" -new_console:d:%USERPROFILE%

2018/7/2 no extra setting need with the latest version of `Cmder(v1.3.6)` and `Win10(17134)` with `WSL(Windows subsystem Linux)`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can type `bash` in your terminal to switch to the bash mode

`exit` to exit

same `sh` for shell